# Why are different pointers and void pointers being used by these functions?

Tags: c, pointers, avr, atmega, eeprom

I have an `ATMega328` and I'm using the `<avr/eeprom.h>` functions to use the inbuilt `EEPROM`.

I can use the `EEPROM` correctly but I don't understand the function arguments I pass to the `EEPROM` functions.

For example, to write different types of data I can use

```
void eeprom_update_byte (uint8_t *addr, uint8_t value);
void eeprom_update_word (uint16_t *addr, uint16_t value);
void eeprom_update_dword (uint32_t *addr, uint32_t value);
void eeprom_update_float (float *addr, float value);
```

- But why does the pointer type for the address (the `addr` parameter) change depending on the function used? If `addr` just points to a valid `EEPROM` address why is the type different in each function?
- Also, the use of the `void *` in the `EEPROM` function below is confusing me. I understand that a `void *` can point to any address, so I'm assuming the function simply writes byte by byte the data in `src` but I'm unsure if this is correct?

`void eeprom_update_block (const void *src, void *dst, size_t n);`

Comment: @milleniumbug if I knew what it was and could link it to my problem then I wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: All data pointers in the language mostly "just point to a valid address". That still does not mean that type safety is useless and/or that all pointers in C programs should be just `void *`. In this case, if you want to call a function `eeprom_update_float`, make sure you supply a pointer to `float` (and not to `int` or somehting else).

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that it would allow you to do `eeprom_update_float(addr + i, value[i]);` in a loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott Since the caller owns `addr` pointer,`eeprom_update_float` might as well take `void*`. The caller wouldn't need to recompile the code, because all pointers convert to `void*` "for free".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was just trying to come up with a reason why the designer might have designed the interface this way rather than use `void *` for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first four functions listed define the type of object being written. So internally the function might look like this:

```
void eeprom_update_float (float *addr, float value)
{
    *addr = value;
}
```

This offers type safety benefits (e.g. cannot write a `float` into a `uint16_t`) by ensuring that the destination pointer is the same as the source variable.

The final version `void eeprom_update_block()` simply writes an arbitrary block of memory to a given address. It probably uses something like `memcpy` underneath:

```
void eeprom_update_block (const void *src, void *dst, size_t n)
{
    memcpy(dst, src, n);
}
```

This version of the function doesn't have any type safety advantages, but can be used to write non-trivial data into memory. For example, a struct can be written like this:

```
eeprom_update_block(&myStruct, dst, sizeof(myStruct));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason behind taking type-specific pointers in the first four APIs. These functions could be redefined with `void*` without the need to recompile code relying on them:

```
void eeprom_update_byte (void *addr, uint8_t value);
void eeprom_update_word (void *addr, uint16_t value);
void eeprom_update_dword (void *addr, uint32_t value);
void eeprom_update_float (void *addr, float value);
```

There is no special alignment requirements in EEPROM, so my guess is that Atmel team used type-specific pointers for aesthetic reasons.

> Also, the use of the `void*` in the EEPROM function below is confusing me.

`eeprom_update_block` is an untyped version of type specific `eeprom_update_XXX` functions. Note that since the second parameter is `void*`, a third parameter specifying block size is now required, while `eeprom_update_XXX` functions imply the size from the type of their argument.